# Magento2 success message

Tags: magento2, messages, global-messages

When we are saving any frontend form, it is showing the success message on same page and also on all other pages.

It also shows the messages after reload.

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend controller save execute method success massage code should like this.

```
try {
    $model->save();
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The testimonial has been saved.'));
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('testimonial_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true));
        return;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Model\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
} catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the testimonial.'));
}

$this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
$this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('testimonial_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('testimonial_id')));
return;
```

Hope this will help, I have also save my custom module testimonial data from frontend and I didn't get repeated success message.