# message2 success message

Tags: magento2.4, success-message

I have the same message issue in this thread [Magento2 success message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135323/magento2-success-message)
However, that post is old and my current version is 2.4.3

Any suggestion for fixing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

> ***Method-1 Using Module***

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages':'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/view/messages'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

> ***Method-2 Using Theme***

**app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

**Must be run Magento 2 commands after adding the above files**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento c:c
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Need to override this file**

**vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js**

Find the following function

```
$.mage.cookies.set('mage-messages', '', {
   samesite: 'strict',
   domain: ''
});
```

Add path on that

```
$.mage.cookies.set('mage-messages', '', {
   samesite: 'strict',
   domain: '',
   path: '/'
});
```

Comment: I tried at this path messages.js /app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js but is not working..